# Macro to hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

(I revise my question) I use Microsoft Excel 2007 and I have never used macros before so I have no idea how to code this. I want every data that I fill into a certain Excel file automatically filling column in another Excel file.

For example

File1

```
No      Name    Date        Price       
1       A       2/3/2013    x   
2       B       3/3/2013    y       
3       C       4/3/2013    z
```

I want the same data from File 1 filling automatically to File 2

```
File 2

Name        Date        Quantity
A       2/3/2013        
B       3/3/2013
C       4/3/2013
```

So next time I need to update data from File 1, I don’t need to check File 2 (File 1 and File 2 are in different file)

What should I do these with Macro Excel?

Answer (score 0):

You may solve this by using plain simple formulas on `Sheet 2`. On the `Name` column cells in `Sheet 2`, add formulas like `=Sheet1!B2`, etc... Same for the cells on the `Date` column.